# CSS: Remove images when screen scales below a certain value

Tags: css

I'm building a responsive layout using the responsive grid system. Once the screen scales below 480px all my elements stack on top and take up 100 percent of the page width. This is great for mobile devices. Images however seem to get in the way and I would like to simply remove them once the screen scales below this value.

I'm using the @media function. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1):

You can use the display:none; attribute in css.

Example:

```
#id_of_image {
    display:none;
}
```

Use this in your @media.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
   img {  //or some specific element
       display: none;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use CSS you're still downloading the images, and there's really no need for that if you can avoid it. You're better off checking for the device on the server, and, if it's a mobile device just omitting the  tag from the page. You can use the Mobile Detect library for this, and then your code would look something like

```
<?php if($device != 'mobile'): ?>
    <img src="">
<?php endif; ?>
```

http://mobiledetect.net

Of course, you can use `display:none` in your CSS as a fallback... :)